# Generate a random matrix in MATLAB with equal number of values less than 0.5 and greater than 0.5

Tags: matlab, random

I want to generate a random matrix of size n such that it has equal number of elements less than 0.5 and greater than 0.5

Comment: Just generate n^2/2 numbers in [0,0.5), and n^2/2 numbers in [0.5,1). Shuffle the whole set and fill the matrix in any pattern (row-wise, column-wise; does not matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will create a matrix with first half of numbers less than 0.5 and next half of numbers greater than 0.5 :-

```
required= [0.5*rand(n,n/2),  0.5+rand(n,n/2)];
```

**EDIT :-**  As now you also mentioned that you want shuffled numbers, add the following in your code too:-

```
required=reshape(required(randperm(numel(required))),size(required))
```

Please also note that this is only possible when `n` is an even integer because half of an even integer is also an integer whereas half of an odd integer can never be an integer!